# In .NET, how to create a stream that has fastest possible Write() method

Tags: .net, multithreading, queue, circular-buffer

I have an application that logs messages to two files in conjuction with sending them over a socket.  One file gets the binary representation and the other gets a human-readable equivalent.  The message class has a function that outputs the human-readable version of the message to a stream.  The binary representation is available in the message class as a byte[].

I want to maximize the outgoing message rate, so I feel that the logging action should be as quick as possible.

One possible approach is to simply create a Task to perform each of the logging actions and pass a reference to the message instance to each task.  The problem with this approach for me is that the message instance is a pooled object and must be returned to the pool at some point.  With multiple threads holding references to the message object, it is difficult to coordinate the return of the message object to the pool such that the last thread using it actually does the returning.  Plus I don't want to create Tasks (or any objects) every time a message needs to be sent.

I believe that the fastest possible implementation of the Write() will have these two characteristics:
1. Will handle the work of writing the data to the file on a different thread than the thread that is sending the message.
2. Will not allocate any additional objects (therefore no chance of pausing for GC).  Since allocation of new memory is not desirable, the Write() method can block until there is enough space to accept the message for Writing.

I'm considering using something like the CircularBuffer/CircularStream here: http://circularbuffer.codeplex.com/ (although this implementation does not block when the buffer is full)

What are your thoughts?

Comment: You should clarify your requirement.  Is it absolutely necessary that the message be written and flushed to a file before it is sent on the socket?  If not, you could easily send the data and queue the buffer object to the logger thread afterwards.

Comment: YourMother - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Martin James - it is not necessary to write/flush to file before sending to the socket.  Your comment about reordering operations made me realize that I'm actually trying to minimize the total time spent sending each message, so I can maximize throughput.  I will edit the original question.